# How to index a data.table with different types of key

Tags: r, data.table

I want to index my data.table by a numerical value with two keys.

How can I do this?

```
url <- "http://leg.ufpr.br/~walmes/data/sao_silvestre_2015-2018.txt"
## browseURL(url)
da <- fread(url)

setkey(da, ANO)
da[J(2016)] # it works fine

setkey(da, ATLETA, ANO)
da[J(2016)] # it doesn't works
```

Comment: Hello, sorry but I don't understand your comment. In 2) e) there are two keys.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html

Comment: Sorry, I was reading on secondary index vignette

Comment: To clarify, do you want to know (a) how to set a key based on two columns, (b) how to set a primary key while retaining an index of a second column, or (c) how to filter/WHERE a table that has a key of two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
da <- fread(url, encoding = "UTF-8") # Get these Portuguese letters correctly read
setkey(da, ATLETA, ANO)
da[J(ANO = 2016L), on = "ANO"] # A bit more verbose, but gets the job done
```